# Canvasjs in asp.net mvc core

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to show index page in two condition state of data with canvasjs chart in asp.net core mvc.Therefore my dataset is

```
public class DataSet
    {
        public List<PermittedAndFloating> PermittedFloating { get; set; }
        public List<WorkCategories> YearlyWorkCategories { get; set; }

    }
```

Then my controller is

```
public IActionResult Multiple()
        {
            DataSet query = new DataSet();
            query.YearlyWorkCategories = _context.REHPData.GroupBy(r => r.BudgetYearID).Select(s => new WorkCategories
            {
                ID = s.Key,
                Name = s.Select(r => r.BudgetYear.BudgetYearName).First(),
                Electrical = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 1).Count(),
                Mechanical = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 2).Count(),
                Civil = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 3).Count(),
                Admin = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 4).Count(),
                Vehicel = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 5).Count()
            }).ToList();
            //ViewBag.DataPointsOne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
            query.PermittedFloating = _context.REHPData.GroupBy(r => r.PowerPlantID).Select(s => new PermittedAndFloating
            {
                PowerPlantID = s.Key,
                PowerPlantName = s.Select(r => r.PowerPlants.PowerPlantShortName).First(),
                PermittedElectrical = s.Where(r => r.ConfirmID == 1).Count(),
                FloatingElectrical = s.Where(r => r.ConfirmID == 2).Count(),
            }).ToList();
            //ViewBag.DataPointsTwo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.YearlyWorkCategories);
            ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
            return View();
        }
```

Please help me.

Comment: which type of chart you want to show ?
also please explain conditional states as well.